# Is there a way to pass request body to FlutterDownloader

Tags: flutter

I have a use case where I need to download image/images n show progress bar or downloaded file in notification panel where i can open it on tap also after image is downloaded just like FlutterDownloader.

Here's how I tried to achieve it :

```
Future<void> _downloadImage() async {
String downloadDirPath;
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  downloadDirPath = (await getDownloadsDirectory())!.path;
} else {
  downloadDirPath = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
}
downloadTaskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: Endpoints.downloadSingleImageUrl(widget.projectId, widget.cameraId),
  headers: {}, 
  savedDir: downloadDirPath,
  saveInPublicStorage: true,
  showNotification:
      true, 
  openFileFromNotification:
      true, 
);
```

}

but the problem is I need to pass request body to my POST request:

```
{
 "name": image.jpg
}
```

how can i do that? Or is there any other package which will let me achieve this?